# Struts Calling Action on page load

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jsp-tags, struts-1

I am new to STRUTS and to this mailing list, so please be patient with me.

What I am trying, is to call an action on jsp load.
I guess I need a javasript function which calls an action and `'onload'` in
my body.

```
function callAction{

... calling myAction.do

}

<body onload="callAction();" ... >
```

Can somebody help me with this issue?

thank you

Comment: Please, could you give us more information on what do you need?  Does this action navigate to some other place, or does it download any data you need to use in your javascript code?

Comment: i need to fill a dropdown with data from my database on each page load 
Now I'm able to do this by clicking on a button, but I want to do on each page load

Comment: Vinoth's answer should work no matter what you need.  If you use his ajax example, you should be able to put your combo code inside his `success` function without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your action like this if you want to navigate to another page,

```
function callAction() {
    window.location = "navigation.do?parameter=showNavigation";
}
```

else if you want to call the same page (without loading another page), you need to use ajax like this. Here i used [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
                                                                    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "navigation.do?parameter=showNavigation",
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Vinoth , your first solution works fine , but what i don't understand is that , although it keeps on executing this action over and over and over! 
do you know why please

Comment: Because you wrote your function body onload and this will call your function (that is moving to another page). It may recursive. You may consider the second option.

Comment: Else you need to call that function only on some button `click` or dropdown `change` event.

Comment: I can not make  work the second solution, how could i call it in jsp onload ?

Comment: You need to add the second script inside of your javascript tag and import the jQuery library in your jsp page.

Comment: Checkout my edited second script. Post if you have any console errors in browser.

Comment: your solution calls the action (.do) but it does not fill the dropdown list, here is my jsp page: 
 <td><select name="rechfich">
  <c:forEach var="fich" items="${nomfich}">   <option value="${fich}">${fich}</option>
  </c:forEach>  
           </select></td>

here's my combobox action:
        request.setAttribute("nomfich",touslesfichiers);
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS_RESEARCH_COMBO);

Comment: You need to do that logic. Set your list into session and forward that into some jsp page. Convert your list value to `<option>` format. This you will get in success as data. Populate that data into dropdown.

Comment: that's work, here's how i am doing:
         <c:set var="p" value="${sessionScope['UserForm']}"/>
         
          <td>Sélectionner le fichier</td>
          <td><select name="rechfich">
          
            <c:forEach var="fich" items="${p.comboliste}">
  <option value="${fich}">${fich}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select></td>
 </tr>
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@user3333294: You can also do in the following way:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitPage(){
                document.forms[0].action = "navigation.do?parameter=showNavigation";
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="mainBody">
        <form method="post" onload="submitPage()">
            ...
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @bansaal: your solution worked fine, but it makes an infinite loop too